# Menu options not showing on Collapsing Toolbar

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I am trying to implement a Collapsing Toolbar Layout with menu options but whenever I set the image view source in the below code, the image covers the menu and the back button.  The options are there as I can click on them, they are just hidden by the image.  Does anyone know how to fix this?

XML Layout

```
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true" app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed" app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/detail_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>

            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/background"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                android:minHeight="100dp"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: Is this within a coordinatorlayout?

Comment: Yes, it all works fine apart from the menu icons not showing

Answer (score 9, accepted):

please try this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/coordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" >

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                android:background="@drawable/background"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:minHeight="100dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/detail_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

if any trouble leave comment

good luck !

Comment: please try to add this inside your toolbar :  android:gravity="center_vertical"

Comment: Can you describe what you've changed between the OP's code and the code in your answer?

Comment: @MichaelFulton: Bring Toolbar to the end. Toolbar will be the last child of CollapsingToolbarLayout

Answer (score 7):

From own experience this tells me this you probably have forgotten to add the following lines to the activity:

> Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
>
> setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

Comment: same thing happened here. I am using toolbar within fragment and forgot to set this code. Suggestion is anyone who met the same issue try this line first, caused it's short and quick to verify.

Answer (score 4):

Try adding collapseMode attributes to the Toolbar...like this. It pins the toolbar.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar


    app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />
```